# Is it possible to restricted time for upload new item?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

is it possible to restricted time for upload new item on sharepoint online?
for example, user can upload new item on working hour. after working hour, the new items button becomes disable and user cannot upload new item or edit list.

Thank you :)

Comment: Create custom form (JS, HTML, CSS), and writing logic in JS or C#, i was doing in this :))

Comment: Hi MelviN,
could you send me the references for create custom form? :)

thank you :)